# JSTL conditional in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I’m trying to use a JSTL conditional statement on a .jsp page in a Spring MVC app.

I have a model called user and an attribute called gender. The value of gender is displayed when I use this line in the .jsp:

```
${user.gender}
```

Specifically, in this case the value is ‘M’. But I want to display a literal ‘Male’ when the value is ‘M’.  Based on the documentation I’ve found, my code should be:

```
<c:if test="${user.gender=='M'}">Male</c:if>
```

However, that doesn’t display anything. Any ideas what I’m doing wrong here?

The gender variable is defined as a String in my User model class.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix. As it turns out, my ${user.gender} value was for some reason getting padded with spaces. Thus, I had to trim off those spaces for the conditional to work. For that I used the JSTL [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) function:

```
<c:set var="genderstring" value="${user.gender}"/>
<c:set var="genderstringtrimmed" value="${fn:trim(genderstring)}" />
```

Then I changed the conditional, which now works:

```
<c:if test="${genderstringtrimmed=='M'}">Male</c:if>
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<c:if test="${user.gender.equals('M')}">Male</c:if>
```

Comment: This ultimately calls the same function that == does in JSTL and would not produce any different results.

Comment: that not true == checks if the string refrences the same instance object while .equals checks if the content of the string are the same. because string is a refrence type

Comment: == checks the reference in Java, but not in EL.
See the "Operators" section here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html
`Relational: ==, eq, !=, ne, <, lt, >, gt, <=, ge, >=, le. Comparisons can be made against other values or against Boolean, string, integer, or floating-point literals.`
I recently refactored many old JSP pages to use EL, and I assure you == does *not* check the reference.